# Custom UITableView Cell is Causing An Error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

My app is a simple RSS Reader that uses a tableview to display the list of articles. In order to display a picture from each of the articles in a tableview cell as well as the title and author of the articles, I used a **custom** `UITableViewCell`. I made a class for the tableview cell and created outlets for the imageview and labels from a prototype cell in the storyboard to the class. The code for my custom tableview cell is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class itemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var itemTitleLabel: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var itemImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var itemAuthorLabel: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

Furthermore, in my **UITableViewController**, I have the following code for the **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath 
indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", 
forIndexPath: indexPath) as! itemTableViewCell

   cell.itemImageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    let item = feedItems[indexPath.row] as MWFeedItem
    cell.itemAuthorLabel.text = item.author
    cell.itemTitleLabel.text = item.title




    if item.content != nil {

        let htmlContent = item.content as NSString
        var imageSource = ""

        let rangeOfString = NSMakeRange(0, htmlContent.length)
        let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(<img.*?src=\")(.*?)(\".*?>)", options: [])

        if htmlContent.length > 0 {
            let match = regex?.firstMatchInString(htmlContent as String, options: [], range: rangeOfString)

            if match != nil {
                let imageURL = htmlContent.substringWithRange(match!.rangeAtIndex(2)) as NSString
                print(imageURL)

                if NSString(string: imageURL.lowercaseString).rangeOfString("feedburner").location == NSNotFound {
                    imageSource = imageURL as String

                }

            }
        }

        if imageSource != "" {
            cell.itemImageView.setImageWithURL(NSURL(string:                       
imageSource)!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
        }
        else{
            cell.itemImageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
        }

    }
    return cell
}
```

I also added

```
    var nibName=UINib(nibName: "itemTableViewCell", bundle:nil)
    tableView.registerNib(nibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    tableView.registerClass(itemTableViewCell.self,     
    forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

into my viewDidLoad() method.

Whenever I run the app, I get the classic `"unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"` error at the

```
cell.itemImageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
```

in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line

```
tableView.registerClass(itemTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

because it's replacing the previous line with a request to instantiate the class without the nib so you don't have anything that's defined in the nib...

---

Based on the comments below both of the code lines should be removed as they're replacing any registration that the storyboard should make. The storyboard cell needs to have the `cell` identifier added so that it's registered during the storyboard instantiation and can then be used to dequeue.

Comment: I did that and got the error message: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/brandonhoglund1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3EB433B8-6ED6-48E2-90F9-63E7FD066620/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/317B3CC1-A9CB-4D2B-833A-D0ED1A5E7084/Ivy News.app> (loaded)' with name 'itemTableViewCell''

Comment: Also, do I even need tableView.registerNib(nibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell") in the viewDidLoad() method?

Comment: Are you using a storyboard or a nib? I assumed a nib based on your code / question...

Comment: I'm using a storyboard but if I delete tableView.registerNib(nibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell") in the viewDidLoad(), I get the error 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard.'